# How to debug pre-BIOS delay during boot?

Tags: boot, bios, hardware-failure, debug

I'm after some support to see if my good old laptop can be saved from being replaced.

It is taking a considerable amount of time to switch on. The problem happens right after power on, while the screen is still blank, before any BIOS screen: the iGPU, dGPU and HDD leds blink alternating and stays like that for some time.

At first it was taking some 10 to 30 s in that state. But it did increase a lot in the last month. This morning it took 5 hours! Strangely at some point, the BIOS does load and boot process continues without errors and the system can be up for days.

While the computer is in that zoobie state, I can hear the cooler fan going on and off about once per minute, and the HDD spin on and off every now and then. Screen is dead blank.

My laptop has a low power iGPU (CPU Intel core i7 4700MQ with Intel HD graphics), a more performant dGPU (Nvidia GTX 765M), 1x8GB RAM,1x 128GB SSD with the system and 1x 1TB HDD. The OS is Linux, but I think that is irrelevant given the early stage of the issue.

When the system is up and running, everything runs fine. Stress tested CPU, memory, iGPU, dGPU, all with good results. I haven't stress tested the drives, but I did physically remove them and tried to boot up and the problem was the same. I have also tested without the battery, connected to power supply. Again, same.

I suspect it might be something to do with the double GPU management. So today I removed the cooler to see if the dGPU could be removed, but the chip is soldered to the motherboard, so no luck there.

It would be a pity to retire this laptop since it performs quite well even if it is about 5 years old, and when it is up, it works nicely.

Any suggestion of what can be going on and how to tackle it?

Comment: You have a hardware issue, see if there are hardware diagnostics in the bios.

Comment: Try to refresh the BIOS to the latest version (very carefully). Only download it from the manufacturer's website.